# How do I make walls that the character cannot move through in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest

I have a 2D pokemon-style game where I am trying to create a wall that the trainer should not be able to move through (the trees). How would I use hitTestObject to test if the character is touching the tree and then make the character not able to move in that direction?

```
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var facingDown:Boolean = false;
var noPressedU:Boolean = false;
var noPressedD:Boolean = false;
var noPressedL:Boolean = false;
var noPressedR:Boolean = false;


char.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2);
this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2(event:Event)
{

if (upPressed && rightPressed)
{
    char.y -=  5;
    char.x +=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mright");
}
else if (upPressed && leftPressed)
{
    char.y -=  5;
    char.x -=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mleft");
}
else if (upPressed)
{
    char.y -=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mup");
}
else if (downPressed && rightPressed)
{
    char.y +=  5;
    char.x +=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mright");
}
else if (downPressed && leftPressed)
{
    char.y +=  5;
    char.x -=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mleft");
}
else if (downPressed)
{
    char.y +=  5;
    char.gotoAndPlay("mdown");
}
else if (leftPressed)
{
    char.gotoAndPlay("mleft");
    char.x -=  5;
}
else if (rightPressed)
{
    char.gotoAndPlay("mright");
    char.x +=  5;
}
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.UP :
        {
            upPressed = true;

            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.DOWN :
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.LEFT :
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;


    }

}
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.UP :
        {
            upPressed = false;
            noPressedU = true;
            lastPressed = 1;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.DOWN :
        {
            downPressed = false;
            noPressedD = true;
            lastPressed = 2;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.LEFT :
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            noPressedL = true;
            lastPressed = 3;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            noPressedR = true;
            lastPressed = 4;
            break;


        };
    case Keyboard.RIGHT && Keyboard.UP :
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;


    }
}
}
```

Pardon the messy coding. ;-;

Comment: Where's your `handleCollision` function?

Comment: How about [Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/)?